# Selenium Webdriver not clicking menuitem based on text, xpath or ID

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I've got some html in a page in sharepoint that looks like so...

```
<span style="display:none">

<menu type='ServerMenu' id="zz28_RptControls" largeIconMode="true">

<ie:menuitem id="zz29_AddColumn" type="option" iconSrc="/_layouts/images/MenuAddColumn.gif" onMenuClick="window.location = '/SiteDirectory/investment/AE/5539/_layouts/fldNew.aspx?List=%7B49B0DF27%2D5F75%2D4721%2DA81C%2DF8FA9F5CB9DF%7D&amp;Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdv%2Dsharepoint%2Ecollercapital%2Ecom%2FSiteDirectory%2Finvestment%2FAE%2F5539%2FEmails%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx';" text="Create Column" description="Add a column to store additional information about each item." menuGroupId="100"></ie:menuitem>

<ie:menuitem id="zz30_AddView" type="option" iconSrc="/_layouts/images/MenuAddView.gif" onMenuClick="window.location = '/SiteDirectory/investment/AE/5539/_layouts/ViewType.aspx?List=%7B49B0DF27%2D5F75%2D4721%2DA81C%2DF8FA9F5CB9DF%7D&amp;Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdv%2Dsharepoint%2Ecollercapital%2Ecom%2FSiteDirectory%2Finvestment%2FAE%2F5539%2FEmails%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx';" text="Create View" description="Create a view to select columns, filters, and other display settings." menuGroupId="100"></ie:menuitem>

<ie:menuitem id="zz31_ListSettings" type="option" iconSrc="/_layouts/images/MenuListSettings.gif" onMenuClick="window.location = '/SiteDirectory/investment/AE/5539/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B49B0DF27%2D5F75%2D4721%2DA81C%2DF8FA9F5CB9DF%7D';" text="Document Library Settings" description="Manage settings such as permissions, columns, views, and policy." menuGroupId="200">

</ie:menuitem></menu></span><span title="Open Menu">

<div id="zz32_ListSettingsMenu_t" class="ms-menubuttoninactivehover" onmouseover="MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)" hoverActive="ms-menubuttonactivehover" hoverInactive="ms-menubuttoninactivehover" onclick=" MMU_Open(byid('zz28_RptControls'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz32_ListSettingsMenu'),event,false, null, 0);" foa="MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz32_ListSettingsMenu')" oncontextmenu="this.click(); return false;" nowrap="nowrap"><a id="zz32_ListSettingsMenu" accesskey="I" href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;" style="cursor:hand;white-space:nowrap;" onfocus="MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid('zz28_RptControls'), this, true);" onkeydown="MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid('zz28_RptControls'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz32_ListSettingsMenu'), event);" onclick=" MMU_Open(byid('zz28_RptControls'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz32_ListSettingsMenu'),event,false, null, 0);" oncontextmenu="this.click(); return false;" menuTokenValues="MENUCLIENTID=zz32_ListSettingsMenu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=zz28_RptControls" serverclientid="zz32_ListSettingsMenu">Settings<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" border="0" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)."/></a><img align="absbottom" src="/_layouts/images/menudark.gif" alt="" />

</div></span>
        </td>
```

There is a "Settings" button (with an ID of zz32_ListSettingsMenu_t) which, when clicked, opens a little dropdown box with several menuitem objects in it.

I can click the Settings object to open the dropdown without problem within Selenium but then when I attempt to click the menuitem revealed nothing happens.  I've put in waits I've tried an xpath of `//menuitem[contains(text(),'Document Library Settings']` or an ID value of `zz31_ListSettings` and even `LINKTEXT` of `Document Library Settings` but nothing seems to work, Selenium just doesnt find it to click it.

Anyone got any ideas I'm drawing a blank...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the usual way is preferred, but if you are stuck, you can sometimes work around it with manually sent key strokes.  I usually do a sendKeys, like so:

```
element.click(); //click on menu to expand it
element.sendKeys( Keys.DOWN ); // key donw once
element.sendKeys( Keys.ENTER); //to select the item
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing the old "down, down, left, left, press return" jazz but after playing about for even longer with it I'm thinking you're probably right... :(

Comment: I do it this way sometimes if I am recording video of my test and I want to re-watch it later.  Doing it this way, I can create a test that looks more like a human is doing it.